# Trying to write a CSV file from a nested dict, keep getting type and hash errors

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

**Question --**
The function will write the data from the dictionary into a csv file. The first column should contain the regions and the rest of the columns the percentages for each respective demographic category separated by commas. The first line of the file should be the header information and each row of data should be on a new line.

Code

```
data_dict = {'midwest': 
    {'AMERICAN INDIAN/ALASKA NATIVE': 19, 'ASIAN': 1357, 'BLACK': 195, 'HISPANIC/LATINO': 295, 'NATIVE HAWAIIAN/OTH PACF ISL': 7, 'WHITE': 4157, 'TWO OR MORE RACES': 283, 'OTHER': 0, 'NO RESPONSE': 276, 'Region Totals': 6589},
'northeast': 
    {'AMERICAN INDIAN/ALASKA NATIVE': 16, 'ASIAN': 1728, 'BLACK': 206, 'HISPANIC/LATINO': 387, 'NATIVE HAWAIIAN/OTH PACF ISL': 4, 'WHITE': 3422, 'TWO OR MORE RACES': 266, 'OTHER': 0, 'NO RESPONSE': 334, 'Region Totals': 6363}, 
'south': 
    {'AMERICAN INDIAN/ALASKA NATIVE': 71, 'ASIAN': 5929, 'BLACK': 1077, 'HISPANIC/LATINO': 2887, 'NATIVE HAWAIIAN/OTH PACF ISL': 13, 'WHITE': 7898, 'TWO OR MORE RACES': 890, 'OTHER': 0, 'NO RESPONSE': 714, 'Region Totals': 19479}, 
'west': 
    {'AMERICAN INDIAN/ALASKA NATIVE': 39, 'ASIAN': 7477, 'BLACK': 204, 'HISPANIC/LATINO': 2061, 'NATIVE HAWAIIAN/OTH PACF ISL': 29, 'WHITE': 4591, 'TWO OR MORE RACES': 1045, 'OTHER': 0, 'NO RESPONSE': 931, 'Region Totals': 16377}}

def write_csv(data_dict, file_name):
    
    Writes the data to csv, adding the header as
    the first row

    Parameters
    ----------
    data_dict: dict
        dictionary with percent differences (pct_dif_dict)

    file_name: str
        the name of the file to write

    Returns
    -------
    None. (Doesn't return anything)
    '''
    col1 = ['midwest']
    field = list(data_dict[col1[0]].keys())
    fieldnames = data_dict[col1[0]].keys()


    with open(file_name, "w") as f:
        w = csv.DictWriter(f, fields)
        w.writeheader()
        for i in data_dict:
            w.writerow({fields: data_dict[i].get(fields)})
```

Comment: what is the issue with your code?

Comment: Looks like your docstring is missing its opening `'''`.  Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Among other problems, you're trying to use a variable called `fields` that you haven't defined.  You define two variables called `field` and `fieldnames`, but neither has the full set of fields that you need, since the CSV is supposed to include the region.

```
def write_csv(data_dict, file_name):
    # Add 'REGION' to the list of keys in one of the pct dicts.
    fields = ['REGION'] + list(next(iter(data_dict.values())).keys())

    with open(file_name, "w") as f:
        w = csv.DictWriter(f, fields)
        w.writeheader()
        for region, pct_dict in data_dict.items():
            w.writerow({'REGION': region} | pct_dict)
```

produces the CSV:

```
REGION,AMERICAN INDIAN/ALASKA NATIVE,ASIAN,BLACK,HISPANIC/LATINO,NATIVE HAWAIIAN/OTH PACF ISL,WHITE,TWO OR MORE RACES,OTHER,NO RESPONSE,Region Totals
midwest,19,1357,195,295,7,4157,283,0,276,6589
northeast,16,1728,206,387,4,3422,266,0,334,6363
south,71,5929,1077,2887,13,7898,890,0,714,19479
west,39,7477,204,2061,29,4591,1045,0,931,16377
```